# Python IRC Bot Stops responding after a while of being open

Tags: python, sockets, bots, irc

Ok. So I've been making a twitch bot because I thought it would be fun to learn python and I thought that it would be good for when I get more into streaming. I made a very simple moderator bot and I started streaming a little bit and I've noticed that after a while it stops receiving messages. I've tried to check if it was the socket timing out but the debug messages don't pop up when that happens. If I restart the bot its completely fine but after a while it does it again

[image: Snapshot of what I mean.]

I don't know what else to provide rather than my code, this was written in python and please tell me if I did anything else dumb in my code too.

Here is my code:

Main Code: http://pastebin.com/5DWk8Dmg

Thanks so much in advance!

If you need my config I'll give it to you, but I can't post any more links.